# There is a quiz created in php, mysql. I do not manage to win some issues

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a quiz for kids, now there are 5 questions (initially, I planned, it'll be 20-25). 
[quiz form pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWWA0.jpg)

And I would like to record kids' answers to the DB (into first_attempt):
[mysql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDvK4.jpg)

Then show kids their result and answers. Now this page is OK:
[result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA1Us.jpg)

But, I have been fighting for 2 days with PHP to Record kids' answers:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $first = $_POST ["first"];
    $second = $_POST ["second"];
    $third = $_POST ["third"];
    $fourth = $_POST ["fourth"];
    $fifth = $_POST ["fifth"];

    $a = "UPDATE first SET first_attempt='$first' WHERE q_id=1";
    $b = "UPDATE first SET first_attempt='$second' WHERE q_id=2";


    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $a);
    if(!$result){
    die('Query failed' . mysqli_error());
  } else {
    echo "Record has been created!";
  }
}
?>
```

This code works and Users can see their score.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $first = $_POST ["first"];
  $second = $_POST ["second"];
  $third = $_POST ["third"];
  $fourth = $_POST ["fourth"];
  $fifth = $_POST ["fifth"];

  $total_correct = 0;

  if ($first == "twenty") {$total_correct++;}
  if ($second == "four") {$total_correct++;}
  if ($third == "a lion") {$total_correct++;}
  if ($fourth == "fifteen") {$total_correct++;}
  if ($fifth == "older") {$total_correct++;}

echo "Your score is: " . $total_correct . "/5";
}
?>
```

Please, help to solve it. Or, advice, if there are any examples.

In advance, Thank you and sorry, for disturbing.

Comment: Can you descript the problem? Please see how to prepare your query (you are exposed to Sql Inject)

Comment: perhaps it would help if you added the entire schema for the database ( or all that is relevant to your quiz )?  My first impression is that the table you have shown will not be sufficient to achieve what I think you want - if there are many users your code will continually overwrite data in the db table

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly, which code is working and which is not? Are you aware that in your first code, your `$b` query is never executed?

Comment: "This code works and Users can see their score." then what's the problem, enjoy if it's working

Comment: (I hope you saw attached pictures to understand correctly).

Comment: (I hope you saw attached pictures to understand correctly). The probles is that ENTERED ANSWERS ARE NOT RECORDED INTO THE DB (comlumn first_attend). I did a query with both INSERT, and UPDATE, without success. And question: how to record 5 answers into that DB? It is OK, if the code overwrite existing data. The second code, which works is - just for total scoring, not for RECORDING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `"It is OK, if the code overwrite existing data."` then I hope that the following can provide some help in solving your problem.

The question is asking for help with recording the answers given by a user into the db table. So if one were to modify your form elements to use an array style naming convention, such as `answer[X]` where `X` is an integer ( and most usefully  that would be the question ID! ) then you ought to be able to add the answers with code like this:

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['answer'] ) ){

        /* Replace with your db connection or modify details */
        $dbhost =   'localhost';
        $dbuser =   'root'; 
        $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
        $dbname =   'quiz';


        mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
        $connection = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );


        try{
            /*
                create the basic SQL statement with placeholders
                and then create the prepared statement object.
            */
            $sql='update `first` set `first_attempt`=? where `q_id`=?';
            $stmt=$connection->prepare( $sql );

            /*
                Bind the placeholders to suitable variable names. These variables
                so not need to exist at this point ( in PDO it is different )
                - they can be called whatever you wish as they will be created
                later whilst iterating over the POST array in the next step.
            */
            $stmt->bind_param( 'si', $answer, $qid );

            /*
                iterate over the POSTed answers, assign the key as the question ID ( $qid )
                and the value as $answer - commit to db.
            */
            foreach( $_POST['answer'] as $qid => $answer ){
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
            trigger_error( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
```

Taking that a little further but using the same code shown above to log the answers to the database but obtaining the answers from the same table and using them to grade the answers given.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <!--

                if you were to use the format as shown below
                the number in the square brackets could be
                taken from the question ID ( ie: q_id )
                which would make your quiz more scalable
                and easier to manage.

                When POSTed, the form would yield something like 
                this in PHP so you can see how easy it would be 
                to construct the necessary SQL:

                Array
                (
                    [answer] => Array
                        (
                            [11] => apple
                            [12] => banana
                            [13] => lemon
                            [14] => cherry
                            [15] => mango
                        )

                )
            -->
            <?php
                /*
                    Select the results from the database following the submission
                    of the form. 
                */
                if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['answer'] ) ){
                    try{

                        $keys=array_keys( $_POST['answer'] );
                        $low=min( $keys );
                        $high=max( $keys );
                        /*
                            assuming the questions are sequential it is possible to perform
                            a query like this ( see below )

                            if they are not sequential one would probably have to do a query
                            using the `IN` selector.. 

                            ie: 
                            select `q_id`,`answers` from `first` where `q_id` in (1,3,5,7,9) etc
                        */
                        $sql='select `q_id`,`answers` from `first` where `q_id` between ? and ?';
                        $stmt=$connection->prepare( $sql );
                        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$low,$high);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result( $qid, $answer );




                        $scores=array();

                        /* iterate over recordset and mark each answer - add to scores array */
                        while( $rs=$stmt->fetch() ){
                            $scores[ $qid ]=$_POST['answer'][ $qid ] == $answer ? 1 : 0;
                        }


                        $score=array_sum( $scores );
                        $total=count( $scores );
                        $percentage=( ( $score / $total ) * 100 );

                        /* The KEY is a percentage score */
                        $messages=array(
                            0   =>  'Appalling! Have you succumbed to the Dark Side?',
                            25  =>  'Very poor - you must work harder',
                            50  =>  'Do. Or do not. There is no try.',
                            75  =>  'Very good but you are not a Jedi yet!',
                            100 =>  'Perfect, Obi-Wan has taught you well!'
                        );

                        /* find an appropriate message based upon percentage score */
                        function nearest($s,$a) {
                            $c=null;
                            foreach( $a as $i )if( $c === null or abs($s - $c) > abs($i - $s) )$c = $i;
                            return $c;
                        }
                        $message=$messages[ nearest( $percentage, array_keys( $messages ) ) ];



                        /* show the user how they did */
                        printf('
                            <div>
                                <h1>You scored %d out of %d</h1>
                                <h2>%d%%</h2>
                                <h3>%s</h3>
                            </div>',
                            $score,
                            $total,
                            $percentage,
                            $message
                        );

                    }catch( mysqli_sql_exception $e ){
                        trigger_error( $e->getMessage() );
                    }
                }
            ?>
            <input type='text' name='answer[1]' value='twenty' />
            <input type='text' name='answer[2]' value='four' />
            <input type='text' name='answer[3]' value='a tiger' /><!-- deliberately wrong -->
            <input type='text' name='answer[4]' value='fourteen' /><!-- deliberately wrong -->
            <input type='text' name='answer[5]' value='older' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```